# The number of source components provided (78) exceeds the maximum (32)

Tags: java, jclouds

Could not find any Google Search results which can hint me what issue is here?  I'm trying to upload ~8 GB file and ran into this issue.  All smaller files up to 20MB got uploaded just fine.  Are there any JClouds parameters I need to set to make putBlob call work with Google Cloud Platform (Storage)?

Similar tests with Amazon S3 worked just fine.

```
org.jclouds.http.HttpResponseException: command: POST https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/...

HTTP/1.1 failed with response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request; content: [{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "The number of source components provided (78) exceeds the maximum (32)"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The number of source components provided (78) exceeds the maximum (32)"
 }
}
]
```

Comment: Which version of jclouds do you use? 2.0.0 and newer should limit the number of GCS parts to 32.

Comment: Using jClouds 2.0.2 at my end.

Answer (score 1):

jclouds has a bug which cannot be worked around via configuration.  I filed [JCLOUDS-1368](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-1368) and [JCLOUDS-1369](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-1369) to track symptoms related to this.  jclouds 2.1.0 will address these issues.